# How to make columns appear without delay in Beamer

Tags: beamer, transition

Is it possible to make the first column start uncovering on the first slide, when the default specification is `<+->`?

If I override it at the first column with `<+->`, I end up with an extra delay slide after "4" appears, and two blank slides at the beginning.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item 1
                    \item 2
                    \item 3
                    \item 4
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item 5
                    \item 6
                    \item 7
                    \item 8
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}`, if it doesn't do what you need? It adds `<+->` to every environment that accepts an overlay specification and that doesn't yet have one. In your example this includes the `columns` and `column` environment, which explains the blank pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` globally, as it adds `<+->` to every environement that accepts an overlay specification and that hasn't yet one. In the example, these are the `columns` and `column` environments as well as the `\item` statements, which explains the extra pages.

You may use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` locally in a column, then it applies only to the `\items`, see below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 1
      \item 2
      \item 3
      \item 4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 5
      \item 6
      \item 7
      \item 8
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can keep the global directive, but switch the automatic overlay specification off for one slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}% activate it globally
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}% deactivate it for this frame
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}% activate it for the first column
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 1
      \item 2
      \item 3
      \item 4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}% activate it for the second column
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 5
      \item 6
      \item 7
      \item 8
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you just want to have an automatic uncovering of the items, use the default specification of the `itemize` environment.

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: FTR, I've added the default overlay specification because this is part of a very long slide deck, and adding the uncover to 40 slides manually is prone to error.